# splitting 6 pin PCI-E cables

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, power

I am trying to add a second graphics card to a workstation. The machine already has a GTX970, and i have a spare GTX550Ti and GTX275 floating around. The 275 requires 2 PCI-E 6 pin connectors, the 550 requires 1. The 970 also requires 2...

The PSU (a 1300W PSU in a Dell Precision T7600) has 2 6 pin cables (used by the 970) and one spare 8 pin.

I cant find any cables to split an 8 pin to 2 6 pin connections (I can find lots that go the other direction), so I am wondering if I can (or should) split the 6 pins into 2x6 pin, essentially giving me either 3 or 4 6 pin cables and a spare 8 pin, or is there a mythical 8 pin to 2x6 pin converter i am just not finding?

PS: There are very few SATA connections in the machine and no 4 pin molex (that i have found) so using that option is out of the question...

Comment: You wouldn't want to use a SATA connections on these devices even if you had the spares to do so.  I personally wouldn't attempt to split the cable yourself.  What do you believe you will gain from adding hardware that old in addition to the 970 that is already installed?

Comment: I had no problem finding a [Y-Split 8 to 6+2](http://www.amazon.com/PCI-Express-Video-Y-Splitter-Adapter-Supply/dp/B00A3OVG4W) cable.  While, it basically is a Y-Split 8 to 2 8 pin cable, its design so you can only use 6 pins if you want.

Comment: @Ramhound the 970 is running a Dell 4K monitor at the moment, and was planning getting the 275 to run 2 20" wings... just to load balance... Im a dev and photographer, not a gamer...

Comment: also, thanks for the link to the Y Split... must have missed that.

Comment: The reference 970 can already support 4 displays.  It should have no problem doing 4k and 20" monitors.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the info. i will try it out and see how it goes.